# Is this Johnsonsgrass

Tags: identification, lawn, weed-control, weeds

I have it all over my newly renovated yard. I believe it was brought in with the back fill when they used to grade my yard after I installed a pool... I think it's Johnsonsgrass, or at least that's the closest I've come to identifying it. It grew from 2" to over 10" in less than 10 days.  When I seeded I used Lesco Teammate seed (20% Rye, 60% (3 type) TTTF, and 20% KBG) fertilized with Scott's starter Fert with weed preventer. The Scott's did a great job on the Grabgrass that started coming in but nothing to this.

Any ideas what it is for sure, and how do I treat it?  I know you are not suppose to pull Johnsonsgrass, but I pulled up 75% of it over the last few days hoping its small enough that the roots aren't that deep.  They pulled right up out of the ground really easy.  But if I was a betting man this is going to come right back, till I find something that actually knocks it out.

[image]

[image]